# Sendmail not masquerading email "Received:" headers

Tags: configuration, sendmail

I followed the instructions from [NixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sendmail-masquerading-configuration-howto.html) site and try to masquerade my emails with the following configuration:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(example.com)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(example.com)dnl
```

and added the following also:

```
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost6.localdomain6)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mail.server)dnl
```

I did a test with:

```
$ echo "Subject: test
From: no-reply@example.com
test" | sendmail -v -fuser@example.com -O NoRecipientAction=add-to check-auth@verifier.port25.com
```

and this is what I receive in the header:

```
Return-Path: <user@example.com>
Received: from mail.server (my.ip.add.ress) by verifier.port25.com id abcd1234 for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Sun, 29 Jun 2014 01:23:45 -0400 (envelope-from <user@example.com>)
.....
Received: from mail.server (localhost6.localdomain6 [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.server (8.14.8/8.14.8) with ESMTP id s5T5XgSa003053
    (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 bits=256 verify=NO)
    for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Sun, 29 Jun 2014 12:34:56 +0800
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by mail.server (8.14.8/8.14.8/Submit) id s5T5XfHR003052
    for check-auth@verifier.port25.com; Sun, 29 Jun 2014 12:34:56 +0800
```

As can be observed, `mail.server`, `localhost` and `localhost6.localdomain6` are still showing up in the Received line. What more should I do to get Sendmail masquerading to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You may change "this host email name" (used in Received headers) defining `confDOMAIN_NAME`.
https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/whoami.html

By default sendmail's masquerading changes only header sender (e.g. `From:` header). It may be configured to change envelope sender (`MAIL FROM:` in SMTP session) and/or header recipients (e.g. `To:` and `Cc:` headers). AFAIK it does not change in anyway `Received:` headers.
https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/masquerading_relaying.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if this is true, then what does the settings `MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl` and `MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl` do?

Comment: MASQUERADE_DOMAIN adds domain to list of email address domains to be rewritten by masquerading, see http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading_relaying.html

Comment: Yes, I read that already, so what is specifically masqueraded in the email by adding those two lines?

Comment: "By default sendmail's masquerading changes only header sender (e.g. From: header). It may be configured to change envelope sender (MAIL FROM: in SMTP session) and/or header recipients (e.g. To: and Cc: headers)"